# Login problem on 18.04

Tags: login, 18.04

Fresh install of 18.04 on an Intel NUC.  Worked at first but now when I get to the login screen, it takes about a minute before my keyboard and mouse respond. My password is not accepted on the first attempt but on the second it is. On finally being allowed to log in, I am presented with a purple screen with no desktop.

Edit: I managed to get back in via a hard reboot but that's not an ideal solution.

Edit 2: Complete shutdown followed by disconnecting from the mains allows me to start up normally next time. Reboot or REISUB leads to issues described above.

[video from fail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EwB4aCfCGY)

Comment: Check you memory and do an update!

Comment: Since the keyboard isn't recognised while booting, I can't get into recovery mode run a memory check.

Comment: 'My password is not accepted on the first attempt but on the second it is. On finally being allowed to log in, I am presented with a purple screen with no desktop.' Please mark yourself as affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1766137), thanks! :)

Answer (score 10):

I ran into a very similar issue, but even a hard reset did not allow me to log in. The last thing I had done before the issue presented itself was install the indicator-multiload package.

I was lucky, and simply logging into a console (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>) and uninstalling the package (`sudo apt remove --purge indicator-multiload`) fixed the problem.

I have not dived any deeper into this issue to see why (or even whether) this package caused said issue, but I postulate that it has something to do with the package's integration with the Gnome desktop.

Maybe you can try to think what packages you might have installed recently that could have interfered with Gnome and attempt to uninstall them. If doing so works, at least you can get back into your desktop environment and troubleshoot further.

Comment: This is my main machine and I really don't have the time to laboriously troubleshoot something like this. Furthermore, all the hard reboots can't have been doing it any good, so I "solved" the issue by installing another flavour - MATE.

Answer (score 6):

This problem could be resolved easily by following commands
Go to terminal mode by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> and login then

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-session
```

If it does not work, try as follow:

```
chown $USER:$USER .Xauthority
```

or try to rebuild .Xauthority

```
  mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak
```

Comment: I upgraded from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and had similar issues to OP. This solution worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: upgrade from 16.04 to 18-04. The chown solved this problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I removed the last package I had installed (Numix theme from PPA), reboot and the session could access.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me on 20.04. None of the ideas above did work unfortunately.

```
  sudo chown -R NEWUSER:NEWUSER *
  sudo chown -R NEWUSER:NEWUSER .*   # to include hidden files and directories
```

My issue was caused by a mismatch of USER ID, for more explanation see [Ubuntu 20.04 - Can’t login after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230434/ubuntu-20-04-can-t-login-after-upgrade/1234771#1234771)