# Not able to login on Gnome Desktop

Tags: 18.04, gnome, login

I am unable to login on Ubuntu 18.04 gnome desktop. I can login with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>.

- First tried

  ```
  sudo apt-get update    
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```
- Then I deleted `~/.local`
- Then I reinstalled Ubuntu desktop and session as suggested in 
  [Login problem on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028831/)
  but there was no `.Xauthority` in my home directory.
- Also renamed `.config`

Nothing helped.

Comment: Check you have some space in your $HOME (home directory), as temporary work files are created by the GUI, if there is insufficient space the login attempt fails & you are logged out (without message).  Login via tty will work (as you describe, allowing you to check you have enough free space in $HOME)

Comment: @guverc: /usr/bin/du -sh /home tells me 3,6G.

Comment: So, that means there's login loop in GUI mode. Right? Have you rebooted the system after installation? Try using another desktop environment if listed by clicking on gear icon in login screen.

Comment: I also tried to login with wayland but currently I don't have this option. I think it disappeared after deleting .local or after renaming .config. I rebooted several times. This is not a fresh installation.

Comment: Do you have more than one keyboard layout installed? There might be a little icon in the upper right corner which let's you select your keyboard layout.

Comment: Sometimes it happens that it switches but I don't see the keyboard icon on the login screen. As far as I know I have only one language (german) installed.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop gnome-shell` again.

Comment: I had a login loop a couple of days back, and also could not find the `.Xauthority` file.  I fixed it by booting to a live USB, and running `fsck` on my disks - it turns out I had some corrupted inodes on my disk.

Comment: @Kulfy: Unfortunately reinstalling desktop didn't help either.

Comment: I downloaded SUSE Leap 15 (gnome) and created a live system.

After booting the suse life system from usb stick (EFI bios) there is the following error: "Oh no! Soemthing has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system cant't recover. Please log out and try again." 

After clicking on logout the login screen is shown with the "Live-CD User". Clicking on it leads me to the same login loop without showing a password field 
yeahh happy looping :-)

Comment: Then try what Charles Green mentioned.

Comment: Kulfy, thank you for the suggestion. I ran fsck. No message. Then I installed lightdm but unsurprisingly still have the problem.