# Domain user login

Tags: 18.04, login

I have strange issue during login. I cannot login faster that after ~60 sec when login screen appears. I have ubuntu 18.04 (it was 16.04 but later upgraded). Before this time I've got error that my password does not work (even though I'm really careful while typing it, for sure it's ok). I'm able to login even without connection to Internet (and domain server) but also after this time (roughly around one minute). I already tried solutions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028831/login-problem-on-18-04) but without luck.

Thanks for any suggestions

Regards

Comment: is it wanted behavior that you have to type in your password? you could turn on autologin if you're the only one with a session on this PC.

Comment: I'd like to  autologin if possible, but I don't know how to enable it. It's not possible from GUI `settings->details->users` like [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-automatic-login-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux). Everything at this settings page is grey and disabled.

Comment: that's by design you have to click on the lock at the top to access the admin options, it'll then ask for your password and then you can enable it.

Comment: Ok, but even after unlocking there is simply no switch to enable autologin for this user

Comment: really could you add a screenshot? oh wait this is a company computer?

Comment: Yes, it's a company computer. https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/5/23/a40e5767cc1e47273c0a50dada19c8f2-full.png
Sorry, it's in polish but in general what is written here:
```Typ konta = Account type (Admin selected)
Hasło = Password
Ostatnie logowanie = last login (currently logged in)```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93998/discussion-between-iwo-kucharski-and-tatsu).