# indicator-multiload blocks login

Tags: 18.04, mount, login

I faced the same problem described in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029159/844402). But when I switch to terminal there is only native language available - not default, nor custom language switches works. Looks like native language is set by default. Same language problem in recovery mode when I run root shell prompt on boot.

Last thing I've tried: Loaded from installation flash and learning how to mount file system type 'crypto_LUKS'.

Any recommendations on how to remove package in such conditions would be nice!

System: Ubuntu 18.04. Lenovo E15 laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to mount encrypted partition with instruction like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/653460/844402).
Not exactly, but it has most keywords that I used.

Then I noticed, that I don't know where package were installed. But I know that I can't boot until it in startup apps. So I removed /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-multiload.desktop and successfully logged in.